# Why do ‘verwundet’ and ‘verwundert’ have such a similar spelling?

Tags: difference, adjective, spelling

*Verwundet* means *wounded*

*Verwundert* means *surprised*

Is there any reason for the similar spelling? The words have nothing in common!

Comment: There are even *identically* spelt word pairs in German (and other languages) that have nothing in common (try to look up *Band*, for example).

Comment: *Verwundet* is an adjective built from the noun *Wunde* (wound), while *verwundert* is an adjective built from the noun *Wunde**r*** (wonder). Related: *to wonder*. So it's similar in English too but English adopted the french *surprise* for the adjective which German didn't.

Comment: *verwundert* does not strictly mean *surprised*.

Comment: ...and *verwundet* isn't strictly an adjective.

Answer (score 6):

The similarity in spelling is pure coincidence:

*verwundet* is an adjective (or rather: participle) derived from the verb "verwunden" and the substantive "Wunde" (*Wound*).

*verwundert* is an adjective derived from the substantive "Wunder" (*Miracle*).

When tracing the etymology of both words, I could not find a common root. "Wunder", apparently goes back to a common root with "Wunsch", while "Wunde" traces back to "wunt".

An interesting, but useless side note: Translate the two substantives your words are derived from to ancient Greek, and find *thauma* ("miracle") vs. *trauma* ("wound") - The greek substantives related to the two German words are spelt very similar again! (And again, this is pure coincidence - So spelling similarities are not uncommon, neither in German nor in other languages. After all, there only are so many letters that go together well...).

Comment: It’s not just the number of letters but also the number of sounds in a language ;) But +1 anyway ^^

Comment: @Jan I was thinking about writing "sounds", so know what you mean - The point is, even if the letters *might sound* different, the words are still spelt the same ;) (Like "weg" and "Weg", for example). I could change to "After all, there are only so many letters that go well together to make up acceptable phonemes in a language", but that might be nitpicking...